# "much too [something]" vs "too much [something]"

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

Which are the differences in meaning and usage between the two expressions "much too [something]" and the most common "too much [something]"?
Are they completely interchangeable?

i.e.:  "much too wise" vs "too much wise"

Comment: Surely that's *much too [something]*, not simply *much too*?

Comment: yes, much too [something] vs too much [something]

Comment: _Too much_ is a constituent, but _much too_ isn't. "How much?" "Too much." vs "*Much too." The _much_ in _much too strong_ means _by a large margin_, and it modifies the whole phrase _too strong_. Whereas _too much_ simply means _overfull_, and can only quantify volumes (i.e, you can say _too much coffee_ or _too much food_, but you can't say _*too much hot_ or _*too much full_.

Comment: Yes - as a quantifier, _too much ..._ = _an excess of ..._, needing a noun group (so, for example, _too much aspirin_) whereas _much too ..._ is a secondary modifier, of an adjective or adverb (eg _much too heavy_, _much too slowly_).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Too much* modifies a noun, a verb, or an adverb, and *much too* modifies an adjective or adverb.

Comment: @Kiron. Yes, quite right, adverbs too.

Comment: And _too much_ says that some limit is exceeded, but not necessarily greatly exceeded; whereas _much too_ says that some limit is greatly exceeded.

Comment: "Too much cannot be used before adverbs and before adjectives without nouns."
https://www.englishpractice.com/words/too-and-too-much/

Answer (score 0):

No, they are not completely interchangeable instead of that they are completely different in grammar .

*Too much* is an adjective which explains the quality of the noun.

Example:

> There is too much sugar in my coffee.

In the above example sugar is noun for which we use the adjective too much.

*Much too* is an adverb which specifically explains the quality of adjective

Example :

> My coffee is much too hot.

In above example hot is an adjective that's why we use much too which is an adverb to explain it.

Answer (score -2):

consider the following phrase:
too big.
"too" gives the adjective a negative meaning. Simply, we use "so", "very", and "too" + adjectives to make them seem stronger. This is while "so" gives the adjective a positive meaning and "too" a negative one. Now, "much" is for more emphasis, like when we say "too much expensive".
On the other hand, "much too" is different. "much" in such a case means "nearly". When one says, "much too expensive" it means "nearly too expensive" yet it is really not that expensive.
:-)

Comment: The second half of this answer (at least) is almost completely wrong.

Comment: Thank god I clicked on that link. In Google search results this answer immediately pops up, and worse, the entry is missing your comment.